# sub child emit an event to the parent of its parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

can sub child emit an event to the parent of its parent directly ?

i.e possible to component-3 child of component-2 emit to component-1 who is the parent of component-2 ?

**component1.vue**

```
<component-2 />
//code
ceated(){
    this.$root.$on('sort-completed' => {
}
```

**component2.vue**

```
<component-3 />
//code
```

**component3 .vue**

````
<button 
@click="doThis" />

<script>
doThis(){
this.$root.$emit('sort-completed', update);
}
</script>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tightly couples child and grandparent, which is pretty much always bad style, particularly as it obfuscates the emit chain. Someone (probably future you) is going to find themselves wondering why the listener on the parent is not called in the parent, but triggered nonetheless, and they won't be happy...

---

That said, the component instance has access to the parent component through the [`$parent`](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#parent) property. With this, you can emit an event to the grandparent:

```
methods: {
  emitToGrandparent(){
    this.$parent.$emit('my-event')
  }
}
```

You can chain this, i.e. call `this.$parent.$parent.$emit('my-event')`

---

In Composition API, you get the component instance by calling `getCurrentInstance()`, the returned object has `parent` and `emit` properties (without the `$`):

```
setup(){
  const instance = getCurrentInstance()
  const notifyGrandparent = () => {
    instance.parent.emit('my-event')
  }
}
```

---

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp, getCurrentInstance } = Vue;

const child = {
  template: `
  <div class="frame">
    Child
    <button @click="notifyGrandparent">Notify Grandparent</button>
  </div>
  `,
  setup(){
    const instance = getCurrentInstance()
    const notifyGrandparent = () => {
      instance.parent.emit('notify', 'Child was clicked')
    }
    return {notifyGrandparent}
  }
}

const parent = {
  components: {child},
  template: `
  <div class="frame">
    Parent
    <child />
  </div>
  `
}

const grandparent = {
  components: {parent},
  template: `
  <div class="frame">
    Grandparent (notified {{counter}} times)
    <parent @notify="incrementCounter"/>
  </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    incrementCounter(){
      this.counter++
    }
  },
}

createApp(grandparent).mount('#app')
```

```css
.frame{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

---

But again, this is poor form. If you must pass on undeclared event listeners, consider at least doing it explicitly, something like:

```
<child v-bind="$attrs"/>
```

```js
const { createApp, getCurrentInstance } = Vue;

const child = {
  template: `
  <div class="frame">
    Child
    <button @click="notify">Notify</button>
  </div>
  `,
  emits: ['notify'],
  methods: {
    notify(){
      this.$emit('notify')
    }
  }
}

const parent = {
  components: {child},
  template: `
  <div class="frame">
    Parent
    <child v-bind="$attrs"/>
  </div>
  `
}

const grandparent = {
  components: {parent},
  template: `
  <div class="frame">
    Grandparent (notified {{counter}} times)
    <parent @notify="incrementCounter"/>
  </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    incrementCounter(){
      this.counter++
    }
  },
}

createApp(grandparent).mount('#app')
```

```css
.frame{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, but the project I'm collaborating to isn't based on the use of `$parent property` it is rather using event bus (as far as I learned allow to exchange data between unrelated components as it is the case in **component-3 & component-1** in my example)

Comment: Oh, using `$root` is probably a hack where events are collected on the one component every child component can access. A bit unfortunate that your question says "emit to parent of parent", which is the question I am answering. Using an event bus works specifically independent of component relation, as does using `$root`.

Comment: When I posted the question I had no knowledge about event bus...
can you explain what is the different between `this.$root.$emit` and `this.$parent.$emit` ?

Answer (score 0):

this is not sustainable and not recommended you can use event bus according to event bus i below:

https://gist.github.com/tachibana-shin/d3139d3f24f51d81cf890439d3a05d0c

Comment: event bus ? can you develop your point and explain how toproceed with it ?

Comment: check out the link i wrote it and also the usage example it's ready to use in practice